# What is this error: "Wshelper: access violation at address 00442A4F in module WSHelper.exe. Read of address 00000028"?

Tags: windows-7

Under windows 7, while shutting down the following error is displayed:

```
Wshelper: access violation at address 00442A4F in module WSHelper.exe. Read of address 00000028
```

What does it means?

Comment: Wshelper is part of the software Wondershare Studio, if you do not use this  software uninstall it using Programs and Features in control panel

Comment: If you need it try, un-install it and re-install the software, or upgrade to the latest version.

Comment: The program is trying to access memory space that it is not allowed to, ask the person who made the software why.